# Creating layered DTO class for Ajax

Tags: c#, dto

I'm currently learning Knockout and I have this requirement that the Ajax call to the API returns a JSON-encoded object that has this structure

```
DocInfo {
   CustomerInfo {
      Name,
      Adress,
      XXXXXX
   },
   ProductInfo, {
       Name,
       Price
   },
   ThirdParty {
       Property1,
       Property2
   },
   Whatever {
       Property1,
       Property2,
       Property2
   }
}
```

I am creating serializable C# classes as DTOs but I'm not sure on how to approach this on the C# class in order to returned to the client side that desired object structure.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to maintain the namespacing in your JSON that you've described here or is that solely to illustrate relationship?

Comment: @DavidL I've edited it out assuming that it was just for illustrational purposes. Alonso, if that was a mistake, by any means revert my edit.

Comment: I'm trying to maintain the namespacing from the c# to the JSON

Comment: @AlonsoQuesada Would they be maintained as one string key in that case?

Comment: Correct, they will be one string keys. I was thinking of doing class inside the main DocInfo class but I'm not sure if that will work

Comment: @Alonso Sorry for the misleading edit. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also obtain the right result with Newtonsoft.JSON:

Working [**.Net Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kbidZ7)

**Result**

```
{"CustomerInfo":{"Name":"A","Adress":"B"},"ProductInfo":{"Name":"A","Price":"1"},"Whatever":{"Property1":"1","Property2":"2"}}
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json; 

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var info = new DocInfo(){
            CustomerInfo = new CustomerInfo(){Name = "A", Adress = "B"},
            ProductInfo = new ProductInfo(){Name = "A", Price = "1"},
            Whatever = new Whatever(){Property1 = "1", Property2 = "2"} 
        };
        var output =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}

public class DocInfo{
    public CustomerInfo CustomerInfo{get;set;}
    public ProductInfo ProductInfo{get;set;}
    public Whatever Whatever{get;set;}
}

public class CustomerInfo{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Adress{get;set;}

}


public class ProductInfo{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Price{get;set;}

}


public class Whatever{
    public string Property1{get;set;}
    public string Property2{get;set;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a LinqPad example:

```
void Main()
{
    var docInfo = new DocInfo{CustomerInfo = new CustomerInfo{ Name = "Todor", Address = "101 Local Drive", XXXXXX = "YYYYYY" }};
    var docInfoJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(docInfo);
    docInfoJson.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class DocInfo
{
    public CustomerInfo CustomerInfo {get;set;}
}

public class CustomerInfo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string XXXXXX {get;set;}
}
```

Result:

```
{"CustomerInfo":{"Name":"Todor","Address":"101 Local Drive","XXXXXX":"YYYYYY"}}
```

You can expand on that as needed.

Let me know if this is not what you need.